# Explode number string and change the format

Tags: excel

I have many strings such as:

> "1.5.22.1.2"

and I would need to pull it apart and put it back together again like this:

> "1.05.22.01.02"

The difference is that there are no leading zero for the first one.

This is a big, "copy, manipulate and paste" job because the strings are used as codes in one of out programs.

Comment: Have you tried using REGEX?

Comment: Sorry I have no experience with REGEX.

Comment: @morne, the first digit will be 1 or 01? Do you expect "01.05.22.01.02" as result?

Comment: The 1st digit will always be "1" or "2", the rest should all have a preceding 0 if bellow 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An unorthodox solution is to open a new worksheet and do the following:

1) Copy all the numbers (1.5.22.1.2) you want to change and paste it into the new worksheet.

2) Highlight the cells and go to the DATA tab and select "Text to Column"S

2a) Select Delimited and hit NEXT

2b) Select delimiters as Tab and Other with just a dot:

[image]

2c) Hit Finished.

Now each of the numbers should be in a new column, and you are going to use if conditions then concatenate them.

[image]

Then you can modify the columns as you wish:

for example I have:

for column 1: `=D6`

for column 2: `=IF(E6<10, CONCATENATE(0,E6),E6)`

for column 3: `=L6`

for column 4: `=IF(G6<10, CONCATENATE(0,G6),G6)`

for column 5: `=IF(H6<10, CONCATENATE(0,H6),H6)`

If this is the output you're after then we can squeeze back together by concatenation:

[image]

The end product is column P or (my column 6)

The formula for the concatenation is: `=CONCATENATE(D6,".",E6,".",F6,".",G6,".",H6)`

Comment: Yeah, the situation is actually complicated with textfiles etc. so this is the most appropriate answer. thanks

Comment: @morne you can add more conditions for each of the columns as you wish, before all columns are concatenated with a "`.`" inbetween each column.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a VBA UDF is simpler:

```
Function FormatThis(oCell As Range) As String
    Dim vValue As Variant
    Dim vSplit As Variant
    Dim lCt As Long
    vSplit = Split(oCell.Value, ".")
    For lCt = LBound(vSplit) + 1 To UBound(vSplit)
        vSplit(lCt) = Format(vSplit(lCt), "00")
    Next
    FormatThis = Join(vSplit, ".")
End Function
```

Call from your cell as =FormatThis(A2)